# How to manually search datatable without updating "search" input field

Tags: datatable, datatables

If I manually call:

```
tabla.search('Advanced:' + search).draw();
```

where "tabla" is a datatable, the "search" input field is updated with the search text.

The fact is that I am implementing an advanced search feature using the same field.

If user enters something in search field (the simple search), grid will refreshes automatically with the search. This is OK.

However, I have an advanced search form. When this kind of search is performed, I need the search parameter that is posted to the server to include all search fields with the word "Advanced:" prefixed. That way, in server side, I can know if the search is simple or advanced.

The problem is that when using the "search" method, the input field is updated with the search content. If advanced search is performed, this text appears in the field, for example:

```
Advanced:Campo_1=936969&Campo_2=&Campo_4=&Campo_7=&Campo_3=&Campo_5=&Campo_6=&Campo_8=
```

Is there way to avoid the search field to be updated?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have created a custom search field and remove the default one.

To accomplish it, I used this dom definition:

```
           dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-4'<\"gridToolbar\">><'col-sm-12 col-md-4'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-4'<\"customSearch\">>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>"
```

Then, in draw.dt event, I added:

```
            $("div.customSearch").html('<div id="facturas_filter" class="dataTables_filter"><label>Buscar:<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="facturas"></label></div>');
            $('#facturas_filter input').on('keyup', function () {
                tabla.search($('#facturas_filter input').val()).draw();
            });
```

Cheers
Jaime